# Not sure how to show a module homomorphism to a finitely generated module is an isomorphism..

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

I have the question: Let $M$, $N$ be modules over a ring $R$ with homomorphisms $f, g : N \longrightarrow M$
such that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. Show that:
(1) $f$ is an isomorphism if $M$ is finitely generated.

No clue how to go about this, also not sure how/if $g$ is relevant at all.

*Note, I believe this is different from Orzech's theorem as in this case, N is not a submodule of M.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Since you gave the tag [tag:commutative-algebra] I assume everything here is commutative?

Comment: Hint: think to the case of vector spaces

Comment: @Trebor yes R is commutative.

Comment: @mad_scientist   *Note, I believe that one can replace $N$ by $g(N)$.